# Trying to read the value of an input field

Tags: javascript

so I've been trying to read the value of an input field using the .value property but for some reason it returns an empty string. While I need the text content inside the input field! so why this's happening and what can I do to fix this!

```js
let itemCount, uncheckedCount, listItem;
itemCount = 0;
uncheckedCount = 0;
listItem = [];

const DOM = {
  btn: '.button',
  input:'.item__text'
};

//Setting Event listeners
var text = document.querySelector(DOM.input).value;
document.querySelector(DOM.btn).addEventListener('click', addItem);
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
  if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13){
  addItem();
  } 
 });

//Event Controlling
function addItem(){
 if (text !== ""){
  console.log(text);
 }else{
  console.log('empty')
 }
 

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container center">
      <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
      <div class="flow-right controls">
        <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
        <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="text" class="item__text" placeholder="Enter Your TODO">
      <button class="button center">New TODO</button>
      <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please get the current value inside the function, so that the latest value is retrieved, when the line gets executed again inside the function.

```
function addItem(){
    var text = document.querySelector(DOM.input).value;
        if (text !== ""){
            console.log(text);
        }else{
            console.log('empty')
        } 
    };
```

```js
let itemCount, uncheckedCount, listItem;
itemCount = 0;
uncheckedCount = 0;
listItem = [];

const DOM = {
  btn: '.button',
  input:'.item__text'
};

//Setting Event listeners
document.querySelector(DOM.btn).addEventListener('click', addItem);
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
  if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13){
  addItem();
  } 
 });

//Event Controlling
function addItem(){
var text = document.querySelector(DOM.input).value;
 if (text !== ""){
  console.log(text);
 }else{
  console.log('empty')
 }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container center">
      <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
      <div class="flow-right controls">
        <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
        <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="text" class="item__text" placeholder="Enter Your TODO">
      <button class="button center">New TODO</button>
      <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```